# Wrong length of Hair in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, hair

**Vertex group controls strands' Length** (I don't using textures, because image sequences are not working with Particle System - it's a known limitation)

I expected to see different values for each frame of timeline, but Animation Nodes **always shows original length** for every spline, even with non-animated weight of Vgroup.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your node tree. It maybe a Blender or Animation Nodes limitation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a limitation in Blender or Animation Nodes. [AN's github](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues) is better suited for this question.

Comment: @OmarAhmad I don't think that makes this question off-topic. The answer *is* that this is currently a limitation of Animation Nodes.

Comment: @ScottMilner Not sure, the thing is, I am not sure if it is a limitation of AN. Maybe it is a bug, a behaviour was expected but it wasn't achieved. That's why I suggested moving the question to github, for the developer to take a look and determine the state of things. I will try to investigate this and provide an answer anyway.

Comment: Does not seem off topic to me either. It could be better explained and more context could be provided. Maybe some answers could be possible if desired results would be explained in more detail and more context was provided about what this is for. Actually forming it as a question could also be useful - there is no question in the text at the moment. This always makes it harder to answer as a question.